# Making simple frequency table

Tags: r

I am attempting to make a simple table in R. The data I have is

```
9, 28, 14, 29, 21, 27, 15, 23, 23, 10, 31, 23, 
16, 26, 22, 17, 19, 24, 21, 20, 26, 20, 16, 14, 21.
```

What I want to do is create 6 equal intervals from 5 to 35 and count how many numbers are in each interval. Then I want to create a table that shows the frequency, relative frequency, and percentage for each interval. I want something that looks like this:

```
Interval   Frequency   Relative Frequency   Percentage
[5, 10]     2           .08                  8
(10, 15]    3           .12                  12
(15, 20]    6           .24                  24
(20, 25]    8           .32                  32
(25, 30]    5           .2                   2
(30, 35]    1           .04                  4
```

I've tried this

```
data <- c(9, 28, 14, 29, 21, 27, 15, 23, 23, 10, 31, 23, 16, 26, 22, 
17, 19, 24, 21, 20, 26, 20, 16, 14, 21)
intervals = c('[5, 10]', '(10, 15]', '(15, 20]', '(20, 25]', '(25, 
30]', '(30, 35]')
frequencies <- hist(data, breaks=seq(5,35,l=7))
table(intervals, frequencies$counts, frequencies$density * 5, 
frequencies$density * 500)
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this, but start with `cut`ting the data into bins, upon which you can call `table`. `as.data.frame.table` returns a data.frame very close to what you want. You can use `prop.table` to add the `relative` column; and the `percent` is just that times 100.

```r
x <- c(9, 28, 14, 29, 21, 27, 15, 23, 23, 10, 31, 23, 16, 26, 22, 17, 19, 24, 21, 20, 26, 20, 16, 14, 21)

df <- as.data.frame(table(cut(x, seq(5, 35, 5))))
df$relative <- prop.table(df$Freq)
df$percent <- df$relative * 100

df
#>      Var1 Freq relative percent
#> 1  (5,10]    2     0.08       8
#> 2 (10,15]    3     0.12      12
#> 3 (15,20]    6     0.24      24
#> 4 (20,25]    8     0.32      32
#> 5 (25,30]    5     0.20      20
#> 6 (30,35]    1     0.04       4
```